# Recomendations for an intelligence test

Tags: measurement, intelligence, test

Is there any culture-fair intelligence test, that is not of public knowledge (that is, the answers can be easily viewed online, or has been used extensively to the point it lacks validity), that doesn't require verbal knowledge or specific education, has a very good reliability, measures G, and is appropriate to evaluate a sample of very intelligent adults (mean in the 95 percentile, so it needs to have a very high ceiling). Is sensitive enough to detect cognitive deficits that in other tests might pass unnoticed (for example, attention problems, prospective memory problems), and has a timed component?

It doesn't have to be free.

Comment: That's sure a lot of requirements. How do you want to use this test?

Comment: Intelligence tests don't measure attention or memory problems.  [Raven's Advanced Matrices (RAPM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven's_Progressive_Matrices#Versions) are non-verbal, reliable, and geared to above-average intelligence adults.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Raven Advanced Matrices must be one of the most used IQ test there is, I can easily find the questions online.

Comment: well, if intelligence tests dont measure attention or memory problems, I would prefer to pass a comprehensive cognitive battery, that also included intelligence. But I fear there would be a lot of missed information anyways.

Comment: By definition, G should be correlated with attention and memory, thats the whole point.  But if Intelligence is a different propiety than say memory or attention, what else could there be missing, even if I pass a cognitive battery of simple cognitive abilities, like memory, or processing speed, and then make a composite or perform factor analysis to obtain G, how can I be sure that there is not an integration aspect to intelligence, the ability to use multiple cognitive abilities synchronously. And what about assimetry? could an extremly good memory be detrimental to general performance?

Comment: I could use Wechsler but takes too long and is culture loaded.

Comment: there should be an easily measured propiety of the brain that is the explanation of variations in cognitive performance across multiple domains and learning. A brain is just a computational system, an ant has some computational ability, despite not having cognitive skills such as planning or problem solving, there is nothing inherently in these skills that define intelligence, i could measure the memory of an ant, but even if an ant is capable of remembering everything i wouldnt say is intelligent. By extension I think there must be an infinite amount of possible cognitive skills...

Comment: But despite G being a general factor, the brain shows remarkable modularity, even with specific types of neurons for certain brain areas... is very hard to actually conceptualize a global propiety that explains performance.